# how to create connected buttons for form controls with bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the buttons on these form controls:

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/24gXOzwwev)

to look like the controls in this example:

[Bootsnipp Example](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ykXa)

Basically I am trying to re-create the Bootsnipp example using Bootstrap3 [Bootstrap 3.1.1] form controls.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="controls"> 

      <div class="entry form-group col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="entry form-group col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="entry form-group col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Would up using a bootstrap form generator that gave me this:

```
<div class="tag-controls"> 

        <div class="entry col-sm-4 form-group ">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="tags[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button" data-target="tag-controls"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Similar to Shawn's answer, which I didn't try I found most of these solutions broke when trying to apply the column sizing to a parent element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap the button in a span with class `.input-group-btn` like so:

```
<input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
<span class="input-group-btn"><!-- DO THIS -->
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
</span>
```

**DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/BNUUlFK5xX**

Comment: Excellent. It's nice to find the answer for such an oddly worded question on the first page of the first google result.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing classes and wrappers and had others that I am not familiar with with 3.x

**http://www.bootply.com/V5fU59ukqE**

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="row">


            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" placeholder="Type something" type="text">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
              </span>
            </div>
           </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" placeholder="Type something" type="text">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
              </span>
            </div>
           </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" placeholder="Type something" type="text">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
              </span>
            </div>
           </div>


      </div>

    </div>
```

For Vertical spacing when it collapses, you need yet another wrapper (Bootstrap forms are wrapper heavy) just inside the column "form-group":

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" placeholder="Type something" type="text">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
              </span>
            </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are button-groups:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: button groups do not work, I updated the bootply with a couple different attempts, but they do not appear to work with an input.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve (I was looking at the bootsnip controls) see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Search engine has landed me on this page but unfortunately it did not provide a solution to my problem. So I post an updated answer here for future readers like me, who did not solve their problem.

### Bootstrap 4 update

Although the accepted answer would work for bootstrap 3, this will not be the case for newer bootstrap versions starting from version 4.

The solution for this version would be

```
      <div class="entry form-group col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">   <----------
          <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
          <div class="input-group-append">   <---------
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="entry form-group col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">   <-----------
          <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
          <div class="input-group-append">   <---------
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="entry form-group col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">   <-----------
          <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
          <div class="input-group-append">   <---------
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

If you wish to have the button in front of the input text you have to use **`class="input-group-prepend"`** instead of **`class="input-group-append"`**